# Change view in emacs dired mode

Tags: permissions, emacs, appearance

What options are there to change the view of a directory in `emacs dired mode`? How to apply it? How can I change it on the fly?

In particular I want to know:

- How to make it show the file sizes in human readable format (MB, GB, ...)?
- How to omit the permissions, owner and group in the list view?
- How to change appearance of symbolic links? (I want it to be displayed like regular files i.e. ***without*** the target, but in another color to indicate that they are links).

Comment: For human readable file sizes, check http://stackoverflow.com/a/2859033/605276 and also check the Dired+ package

Comment: Yes, read `man ls` and then experiment with the options to make ls work the way you want Dired to list files. Then, put (for example) this in `.emacs`: `(setq dired-listing-switches "-lBhX")` Human readable is `ls -h`, so that is the `h`. (I suppose `-l` is highly recommended. The rest is just what I use.)

Comment: @EmanuelBerg Thanks, then the `ls` option `-gohL` would be closest to have what I wanted... Do you know how to hide also the permissions and how I can apply this on the fly without editing my `.emacs` file?

Comment: About permissions, I don't know. About on the fly, `M-x set-variable RET dired-listing-switches RET "-gohL"`, then `M-x dired` (or `C-x d`) to see the result. Also, you could put several lines like this `(setq dired-listing-switches "-lBhX")` (with different options) in `*scratch*`, then, with the cursor just to the right of the right parenthesis, hit `C-x C-e`. This will probably give you even faster testing.

Comment: @EmanuelBerg Can you convert your comment into an answer, then I can accept it (even though it doesn't solve the permission question)?

Comment: What's the urgency? It is better the question is open until everything is resolved. Not to forget, **you** might be able to give a full answer (get away with the permissions) in just a few weeks. But I'm happy I could help you, my pleasure :)

Comment: @EmanuelBerg I agree with you and think that the question should be open until everything is resolved. However I just got several times the advice to work on my accepting rate... since then I try to accept faster and also answers which do not solve the problem in every detail

Comment: @student: I read `man ls` the other day and found something interesting: "`-D`, `--dired` generate output designed for Emacs' dired mode"

Answer (score 3):

Remember that in `dired` mode, the `s` option will toggle the sort order, but with a prefix argument, will let you change the switch to `ls`.

From http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dired-Updating.html:

> `C-u s` switches `<RET>` lets you specify a new value for `dired-listing-switches`.

So when I want human-readable sizes listed in my `dired` buffer, I type:

```
C-u s -lah <enter>
```

and you'll see what you need. Ditto for any other options to ls.